# Using dictionaries produced by a function in a future function

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments

I have a function that creates 2 dictionaries which are formatted as shown below, I want to use these 2 dictionaries in a future function.

eg:

```
def some_function():
    dict1 = {'key1':['1', '2'], 'key2':['3', '4']}
    dict2 = {'key3':['5', '6'], 'key4':['7', '8']}
    yield dict1
    yield dict2

def some_other_function(dict1, dict2):
    "some code using dict1"
    "some code using dict2"
```

however I am told that dict1 and dict2 aren't defined, I would have thought that by returning it from a function I could use it as an argument in a future function. I don't want to have to set a global variable.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me. You seem to be missing some basic knowledge about variable scopes and how to manipulate data. Why do you expect to be able to use 2 local dicts as locals in another function without passing their values or using globals?

Comment: Not sure I get your logic either, why not just return both dicts and use `dict1,dict2 = some_function()`

Comment: `dict1` and `dict2` are just names which reference objects. The names only exist within the scope of the functions. The names in `some_function` are in no way related to the names in `some_other_function`.

Comment: Do you know what `yield` does?

Answer (score 1):

You've left off some code here - how is `some_function()` being called in the first place? I assume it's called at the bottom and your actual code is this:

```
def some_function():
    dict1 = {'key1':['1', '2'], 'key2':['3', '4']}
    dict2 = {'key3':['5', '6'], 'key4':['7', '8']}
    yield dict1
    yield dict2

def some_other_function(dict1, dict2):
    "some code using dict1"
    "some code using dict2"

some_function()
some_other_function()
```

What you need to do is `return` the dicts from the first function and pass them to the second function. Like this:

```
def some_function():
    dict1 = {'key1':['1', '2'], 'key2':['3', '4']}
    dict2 = {'key3':['5', '6'], 'key4':['7', '8']}
    return dict1, dict2

def some_other_function(dict1, dict2):
    "some code using dict1"
    "some code using dict2"

dict1, dict2 = some_function()
some_other_function(dict1, dict2)
```

Right now, `dict1` and `dict2` go out of scope as soon as `some_function` ends. `yield` is not the same as `return`... as far as I know, `yield` should only be used within a function decorated by the context manager decorator or within a `generator`.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing is coming in mind.

Make a tuple and return it from first function. Then pass the tuple as another's argument and unpack it within it.

```
def some_function():
    dict1 = {'key1':['1', '2'], 'key2':['3', '4']}
    dict2 = {'key3':['5', '6'], 'key4':['7', '8']}
    tup = (dict1, dict2)
    return tup


def some_other_function(dict1, dict2):
    print dict1
    print dict2


a,b = some_function()
some_other_function(a,b)
```

You can use zip() too

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to `yield` the dictionaries???

How about this:

```
# call some_other_function directly

def some_function():
  dict1 = {'key1':['1', '2'], 'key2':['3', '4']}
  dict2 = {'key3':['5', '6'], 'key4':['7', '8']}
  some_other_function(dict1, dict2)

def some_other_function(dict1, dict2):
  # dict1 and dict2 will now be defined
```

or option 2:

```
def some_function():
  dict1 = {'key1':['1', '2'], 'key2':['3', '4']}
  dict2 = {'key3':['5', '6'], 'key4':['7', '8']}
  return (dict1, dict2)

def some_other_function(dict1, dict2):
  # do something here with dict1 and dict2

# call some_function() and pass the results to some_other_function()
(d1,d2) = some_function()
some_other_function(d1,d2)
```